# Pandas dataframe. Convert weight measurments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas data frame which includes a weight column with various measuring units. There is KG, g, oz, ml, incorrect entries (mix of letters/numbers, these need to be deleted) and some that say 12 x 100g for example. I would like to convert each row to KG to 1dp (including the entries that say 12 x 100g) and delete the nonsense entries.

I have tried using quantiphy but it throws an invalid number error for the non-numbers and 12 x 100g type rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include an example. Also, you need to be more specific about about the requirements

Comment: You could first detect and handle the two 'special' cases - such as change non-numbers to Zero; parse and convert A x B entries. Both processes are not difficult in Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the unit conversion question. To cleaning up the numbers you can look that part up.

For the unit conversion make a function you will need a dictionary for each the equivalent unit set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert_si(val: float, unit_in: str, unit_out: str) -> float:
    SI = {'mm': 0.001, 'cm': 0.01, 'm': 1.0, 'km': 1000.0}
    return val * SI[unit_in] / SI[unit_out]
```

**Tests:**

```
>>> convert_si(1, 'm', 'km')
0.001
>>> convert_si(1, 'km', 'm')
1000.0
>>> convert_si(1, 'cm', 'm')
0.01
```

**Use apply for pandas df.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"amount": [0.1, 10.1, 80000,3000, np.nan, 2200 ], "in": ['km', 'm', 'mm', 'cm', 'km','cm']})
df['return'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_si(x['amount'], x['in'], 'km'),axis=1)
print(df)
```

**results**

```
    amount  in  return
0      0.1  km  0.1000
1     10.1   m  0.0101
2  80000.0  mm  0.0800
3   3000.0  cm  0.0300
4      NaN  km     NaN
5   2200.0  cm  0.0220
```